# Como faço a leitura de um DataGrid, linha por linha?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um `DataGrid` *(WPF)* sendo preenchido por uma fonte de dados externa. Preciso rodar a grid inteira, consultando os valores de cada linha, coluna por coluna.

- Como é possível fazer isso?
- Qual é o "coração" dos dados de um grid?
- Consigo transformar os dados numa coleção e então usar um `foreach` pra rodar e consultar?
- Terei acesso a todas as colunas assim?

Comment: Porque não consultas os dados diretamente? A grelha é UI e devia ser usada apenas pelo utilizador e não pela lógica aplicacional.

Comment: Traduza a nível de estagiário (risos) e coloque como resposta, fico grato.

Comment: O que estás a fazer é o equivalente a imprimir os dados em papel e depois fazer OCR para processar os dados. Deves processar os dados diretamente da fonte de dados. A mesma que atribuíste à grelha.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, também acho desnecessário jogar na grid, é apenas um processo a mais, mas me pediram assim...

Comment: E o motivo de eu estar pegando os dados da grid é aprendizado, mexo pouco com grids, preciso aprender a manipular um pouco...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Se os dados tiverem um tipo definido como apresentado nesse exemplo (Modelo), você pode recuperar os itens de várias formas, veja o exemplo:***

<sup>***Obs: se não tiver tipo de dados o último exemplo é o mais apropriado***</sup>

*Exemplo:*

***Modelo:***

```cs
public class Modelo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

***Preenchendo:***

```cs
GridDados.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
GridDados.ItemsSource = new List<Modelo>(){
    new Modelo(){Id = 1, Nome = "Fulano 1"},
    new Modelo(){Id = 2, Nome = "Fulano 2"},
};
```

***Recuperando***

```cs
List<Modelo> modelos = GridDados.Items.OfType<Modelo>().ToList();
```

*ou*

```cs
foreach (Modelo modelo in GridDados.Items.OfType<Modelo>().ToList())
{
    int id = modelo.Id;
    String nome = modelo.Nome;
}
```

*ou*

***Se o dado for um tipo anonimo:***

```cs
GridDados.ItemsSource = new object[]{
            new {Id = 1, Nome = "Fulano 1"},
            new {Id = 2, Nome = "Fulano 2"},
        }.ToArray();

foreach (dynamic item in GridDados.Items)
{
    int id = item.Id;
    String nome = item.Nome;
}
```

***Debugando para descobrir o item:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `dynamic` nesse caso especifico vai assumir em tempo de execução o tipo que cada item da lista. Como essa `Collection` possui um tipo da *class* `Modelo` a variável `item` assumi esse ***tipo***. Ou seja, "O tipo dynamic é um tipo estático que é definido pela palavra reservada dynamic sendo que a princípio a variável desse tipo pode ser TUDO, e, em tempo de compilação o tipo dynamic assume qualquer operação." (*Marcorrati.Net, C# - O tipo de dados Dynamic, 2014. Disponível em: http://www.macoratti.net/11/02/c_din1.htm. Data de Acesso: 26.jun.2014*)

*ou*

***Com DataRowView:***

```cs
foreach (DataRowView item in GridDados.Items.OfType<DataRowView>().ToArray())
{
      string CDESC_INEP = item["CDESC_INEP"].ToString();                    
}
```

*Referências:*

- [C# - O tipo de dados Dynamic](http://www.macoratti.net/11/02/c_din1.htm)
- [Usando o tipo dynamic (Guia de Programação em C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264736.aspx)
- [dynamic (Referência de C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264741.aspx)
- [ItemsControl.ItemsSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DataGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Classe DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No meu caso o Grid é preenchido a partir de um arquivo DBF. Tentei utilizar, como você disse em caso de os dados não possuirem tipo, a ultima opção. Meu `item` não tem acesso a qualquer propriedade, acho que pelo fato do tipo ser definido em tempo de execução de acordo com o que tu me passou referente a dynamic. Se eu digitar as propriedades (header das colunas?) funciona?

Comment: Então, a última serve para isso vamos dizer que seu modelo é tipo anonimo o dynamic pega os itens de cada posição, vou editar e colocar esse exemplo

Comment: Editei novamente o último item, qualquer coisa nesse linha do `foreach (dynamic item in GridDados.Items)` coloque um breakpoint e pegue o tipo que vai sair

Comment: os meus itens são DataRowViews... consegui acessar os valores por propriedades dessa forma aqui 
`DataRowView drv = dgdDados.Items[1] as DataRowView;
txtCaminhoDbf.Text = drv["CDESC_INEP"].ToString();`

Comment: @CaiqueC. é só colocar assim no lugar de Modelo coloque DataRowView: assim: `foreach (DataRowView item in GridDados.Items.OfType<DataRowView>().ToList())`. Lógica é a mesma do exemplo só o tipo que você deve especificar!

Comment: Hum, ok, muito obrigado, vou testar aqui.

Comment: eu edite ve se funciona contigo...

Comment: Funcinou perfeitamente! Obrigado, foi muito util, não sei se o problema sou eu, mas é dificil encontrar artigos sobre manipulação de dados em grids... Talvez seja facil e eu que estou apanhando de bobo rs